# Google Drive not Loading pdf Link

Tags: javascript, html

I shared the link to the file on Google Drive with anyone who has the link, and for some reason my PDF doesn't show up. It works for someone else's Google Drive link but not for my link.

I've tried sharing it with the whole internet on the UI in Google Drive but nothing changed. Just a blank page.

```
<!-- simple.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Drive not Working for Me</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object data="https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IcEechL2QV5enxoec-B5jhfCaJ9xkzU/view?usp=sharing"  width="600" height="750">
            <embed src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IcEechL2QV5enxoec-B5jhfCaJ9xkzU/view?usp=sharing" width="600px" height="750px" />
            <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IcEechL2QV5enxoec-B5jhfCaJ9xkzU/view?usp=sharing">View the PDF</a>.</p>
        </embed>
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to see my PDF, but all I see is a blank page.

Here's [My Page](http://ourgoodguide.com/Google_Drive_Not_Working_For_Me.html) not working.

Here's [Someone else's Google Drive Link Working](http://ourgoodguide.com/Google_Drive_Working_For_Someone_Else.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the URL with `/preview` rather than `/view` as in your example;

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileId}/preview
```